# Wordpress: Don't show the first inserted post

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I have some subcategories, and in each category I insert some posts, when I show the posts for each subcategory I don't want to show the FIRST inserted post in that subcategory, only the posts that are not the FIRST ONE.How can I do this with query_posts..or how?

Best Regards

//SOLVED I will use a custom field

Answer (score 0):

[See offset parameter in function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Offset_Parameter)

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=5&offset=1');
```